# GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE when trying to append to Google Sheets API V4

Tags: android, api, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, credentials

I've been encountering a plethora of issues with this current project, which can be found in the other questions that I have posted on StackOverflow (one of which is unsolved), but after dodging my other issue in a way that allows me to test, but not actually release, the app, I've encountered another error;
In this code:

```
public class AsyncSheetUpdater extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Master activity;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        GoogleAccountCredential credential;

        Sheets mService;

        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(activity.getApplicationContext(), Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                .setSelectedAccountName("oscarcookeabbott@gmail.com");

        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        mService = new Sheets.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(activity.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setSheetsRequestInitializer(new SheetsRequestInitializer("AIzaSyBreJks4awhrSbyqGkZhgR4rAA61vg0t-g"))
                .build();

        ValueRange values = new ValueRange();
        values.set("EMAIL", "[INSERT EMAIL]");
        values.set("AUTH", "[INSERT DATE]");
        values.set("SUB", "[INSERT DATE + MONTH]");

        try {
            mService.spreadsheets().values().append("1meAAvjdPmghn6wl_IKc-_NJx_M85I_yqsn4Nwm_j_X0", "Users", values)
                    .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                    .execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "SheetUpdate Exception: ", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

It is returning this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:301)
   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
   at com.pybuspr.listeau.AsyncSheetUpdater.doInBackground(AsyncSheetUpdater.java:58)
   at com.pybuspr.listeau.AsyncSheetUpdater.doInBackground(AsyncSheetUpdater.java:20)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzbt(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze$1.zzbu(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zzc(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:269)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:294)
```

This is what my Google APIs Credentials look like:
[image]

I was really hoping that sheet editing was going to be simple, such as how you can use a straight JSON feed of a Sheet without using the APIs, but it seems I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, and I solved it this way:

First, when you debug, Android Studio, as default, use a different keystore than the one you normally use when you compile and sign your APK for release.
This means that you have **two** different keystores with **two** different keys that have **two** different SHA1 fingerprints.

The keystore that is being used for the debug is located by default in the following path *"~/.android/debug.keystore"*, while the one you use for the release version can be wherever you want, since you have to manually create it.

The keystore created by Android Studio for your debug version contains a key named *androiddebugkey*, and it's default password is *android*, same as the password for the keystore.

Now, here's what you have to do:

1) Open the command line

2) Using the keytool command, type `keytool -exportcert -keystore <path-to-debug-or-production-keystore> -list -v`

3) Type the password (*android*), get the SHA1 key from what it displays you and add it into your API interface.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#debugmode